# Select query for entity with a condition on joined table matching only one row but return the entity with all childs from that joined table

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to make a select query for an entity when all I know is a value of a column in a child table?
For example, I have a table `crop`

```
crop_id  | name
------------------
1        | Fruit
2        | Berry
3        | Vegetable
```

And I have a table `harvest`

```
harvest_id | crop_id | name
----------------------------
1          | 1       | Apple
2          | 2       | Blueberry
3          | 1       | Orange
```

This is a one-to-many relationship between `crop` and `harvest`.
Now I only know the value 'Apple' and I want to make a query that selects a single row from `crop` and joins each child row that is of the same 'type' as 'Apple'.

The following query would only yield Fruit with Apple, but I would like Fruit with Apple and Orange

```sql
select *
from crop c
left outer join harvest h on c.id=h.crop_id
where h.name = 'Apple'
```

Can I do this with a single select query? I do not wish to make 2 separate queries, one for Apple to get its crop_id and then another one for the crop by id with children.

Comment: please provide expected output.

Comment: I believe 'I would like Fruit with Apple and Orange' should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want using only `'Apple'` to find all fruits?

```
select *
from crop c
left outer join harvest h on c.crop_id=h.crop_id
where h.crop_id = (select crop_id from harvest where name = 'Apple')
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c8cbdb5bf28e231a439599ee02a4d48b)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're aiming for? You can get the crop_id with your query. Then you can use the result as a select query in another query.

```
select *
from crop c left outer join harvest h on c.crop_id=h.crop_id
where c.crop_id = (select h.crop_id from crop c left outer join harvest h on c.crop_id=h.crop_id where h.name = 'Apple')
```

Comment: This does not seem quite right. Wouldn't this return just the crop without the childs?

Comment: Youre right. My point was the using result as a select query. To work as you want it need to left outer join with harvest table in first query. Just edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Join crop to harvest, then to another harvest.

> ```
> select h2.*, c.name as crop_name
> from harvest h1
> join crop c using (crop_id) 
> left join harvest h2 using (crop_id) 
> where h1.name = 'Apple'
> order by h2.harvest_id;
> ```

| harvest_id | crop_id | name | crop_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Apple | Fruit |
| 3 | 1 | Orange | Fruit |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d11dae6f51e7442500b8717a40d110c5)*